# Are attributes not considered to be nodes anymore?

Tags: html, dom

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) `ATTRIBUTE_NODE` is deprecated. Why don't attributes possess a `nodeType` anymore? Are they no longer considered to be nodes?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing, but I never doubted the spec. Do you have a specific issue that needs a workaround? StackOverflow is for specific coding issues, not for discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr):

> **Warning**: In DOM Core 1, 2 and 3, `Attr` inherited from `Node`. This is no
>   longer the case in [DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/). In order to bring the implementation of `Attr`
>   up to specification, work is underway to change it to no longer
>   inherit from `Node`. You should not be using any `Node` properties or
>   methods on `Attr` objects.